# Using Image as layout

Tags: android, layout

I wanted to create a cool layout background, so I created an image which will serve as layout instead.

My image is of 320X480 resolution which will serve ideal for mdpi resolution mobiles but what about bigger screen size handset.

**My Question: Should I create several images(here my layout) of different sizes for different size handset OR there is a code which will just resize the image when opened in different size handset.**

Comment: A layout is a combination of views and view containers. An image cannot be a layout, but it can be the background of a layout. If you want to support clean graphics on different resolutions you have to make different images.

Answer (score 1):

> To create a image for different densities, you should follow the
>   2:3:4:6:8 scaling ratio between the five primary densities (medium,
>   high, x-high, xx-high, and xxx-high respectively). For example,
>   consider that the size for a launcher icon is specified to be 48x48
>   dp. This means the baseline (MDPI) asset is 48x48 px, and the high
>   density (HDPI) asset should be 1.5x the baseline at 72x72 px, and the
>   x-high density (XHDPI) asset should be 2x the baseline at 96x96 px,
>   and so on.

You should refer official website of android for that for more information:
[Link 1](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html)

Comment: I get that but can you tell me, if I can just use a 9-patch image for background and it will be resized automatically for diff screens.

Comment: you must ask new question for another query not related to this question @Mohit